# Can't delete a file using Ant

Tags: file, ant, delete-file

I want to use ANT script to delete a file.

For some reason the following script gives me the following message:

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
```

The script I am running is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<project name="UpdateFlag"> 
    <target name="deleteFlag">  
        <delete file="/state/update.flag" failonerror="true"/>      
    </target>
</project>
```

Please assist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<delete file="/state/update.flag" failonerror="true"/>
```

Will delete the file that's is in the state directory that's on the root of your directory structure. In Unix, it would be `/state/update.flag`, and in Windows (on the C: drive), it would be `C:\state\update.flag`. Is this where the file is located?

When in doubt, run Ant with the `-d` and `-v` switches. This will print out lots of useful information (and tons of useless garbage). For example, did your delete task find a file to delete? If the file isn't there, the `<delete>` task won't fail.

I have a funny feeling that you actually meant to do:

```
 <delete file="${basedir}/state/update.flag"
    failonerror="true"/>
```